# Pythonic way to create a list of diminishing sequences

Tags: python

Instead of doing:

```
l_1 = range(0, 10056, 24)
l_2 = range(0, 10032, 24)
l_3 = range(0, 10008, 24)
...
l_419 = range(0, 0, 24)
l_together = list(l_1, l_2, ..., l_419)
```

How can I create a list of lists with diminishing sequences in a more Pythonic way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a simple list-comprehension:

```
[range(0, i, 24) for i in reversed(range(0, 10056 + 1, 24))]
```

Which is equivalent to the simple for-loop:

```
result = []
for i in reversed(range(0, 10056 + 1, 24)):
    result.append(range(0, i, 24))
```

Either one of those is perfectly fine and pythonic.

Or, to demonstrate with a reduced example:

```
>>> n = 100
>>> step = 10
>>> result = [range(0, i, step) for i in reversed(range(0, n+1, step))]
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(result)
[range(0, 100, 10),
 range(0, 90, 10),
 range(0, 80, 10),
 range(0, 70, 10),
 range(0, 60, 10),
 range(0, 50, 10),
 range(0, 40, 10),
 range(0, 30, 10),
 range(0, 20, 10),
 range(0, 10, 10),
 range(0, 0, 10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bigL = []
diminish = 24
i = 10056
while i >= 0: ## Just abstracting the code to easily modify it ... this will run while i is positive
    bigL.append(range(0, i, diminish)) ## Supply i and diminish and then append the list to bigL 
    i -= diminish ## Reduce i by diminish (by 24 in this case)
```